# Create a delegate with arbitrary parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, delegates

I have a System.Reflection.MethodInfo and would like to have a method that creates a delegate(preferably a Func<...> or an Action<...>) that represents that method, given an instance to invoke it on.

So ideally I would like something like the following psuedo-code:

```
public TDelegate GetMethod<TDelegate>(MethodInfo methodToRepresent, object instanceToInvokeOn)
{
    return (TDelegate)((parameters....) => methodToRepresent.Invoke(instanceToInvokeOn, all parameters in an object[]));
}
```

where TDelegate represents the signature of the represented method. If the signatures don't match, an exception should be thrown.

I realise I probably can't achieve this with a simple lambda expression, since its parametertypes must be known at compile-time. Perhaps I need to construct a delegate from scratch? Is it possible to create a delegate by specifying its body and parameters seperately?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. But perhaps you want this:

```
public TDelegate GetMethod<TDelegate>(MethodInfo methodToRepresent, object instanceToInvokeOn)
  where TDelegate:class
{
   return (TDelegate)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate), instanceToInvokeOn, methodToRepresent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the Delegate.CreateDelegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following method.  Note that you can't really create a generic `Action<...>` using this method because, as you say, the types are not known at compile time.  But this gets you pretty close.

```
public delegate void DynamicInvokeDelegate(params object[] args);

public static DynamicInvokeDelegate CreateDynamicInvokeDelegate(MethodInfo method, object instance) {
    return args => method.Invoke(instance, args);
}
```

If you need the delegate to return a value:

```
public delegate object DynamicInvokeWithReturnDelegate(params object[] args);

public static DynamicInvokeWithReturnDelegate CreateDynamicInvokeWithReturnDelegate(MethodInfo method, object instance) {
    return args => method.Invoke(instance, args);
}
```

**EDIT:**

It actually looks like you might be wanting this code:

```
public static T GetDelegate<T>(MethodInfo method, object instance)
    where T : class
{
    return (T)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), instance, method);
}
```

The `(object)` cast is required, since the compiler will not allow you to cast `Delegate` to any random type, and you cannot constrain `T` to be a delegate.  Casting through object satisfies the compiler.

Comment: Yup, thats about identical. I wouldn't have settled for the solution with the params object[], though. Thnx anyway

Comment: OT: but I just wanted to say welcome and congrats after a really successful and active first week on stackoverflow. Thanks for contributing ;p